# Mysql query does not work, displays an empty field

Tags: php, mysql

The first table with posts (posts with columns: id, post_id, post_name, post_date)

The second table with a view counter (post_views with columns: id, post_id, post_views).

```php
$count_boards = $db-> super_query ("SELECT * FROM posts AS p
JOIN post_views AS pv ON p.post_id = pv.post_id
WHERE p.post_date> = (CURDATE () - INTERVAL 3 DAY) ";

$count_boards = $count_boards['post_views'];
echo $count_boards;
```

When outputting, it doesn’t output anything, that is, it is empty ... What could be the problem?

Comment: What is "`super_query`"? Also, I hope the spaces between $ and the var names are just a copy fault and not in your code.

Comment: Did you check your error logs?

Comment: Please remove the spaces.

Comment: `$count_boards = $db->super_query("SELECT * FROM posts AS p
JOIN post_views AS pv ON p.post_id = pv.post_id
WHERE p.post_date> = (CURDATE () - INTERVAL 3 DAY) ";

$count_boards = $count_boards['post_views'];
echo $count_boards;`

Comment: @keaks88 just edit your question...

Comment: Try `echo` $count_boards before the line that says, `$count_boards = $count_boards['post_views'];`

Comment: super_query = mysql_query